# How to restore files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a maven project.

I am having trouble in restoring my xml files, which were in src/main/resources. (Deleted accidentally)

I tried doing it with "Restore from local history", there I am getting name of the files but when I select those files and try to restore, it is showing me error.

**Error : Cannot replace resource (reason: state is not valid or might have expired)**

Comment: Don't touch mvn nor Eclipse and search manually in build/main/resources, maybe there are still somewhere? No idea about Eclipse history, I switched it off as useless. Use version control, push to server (bitbucket is free) and you'll be damn safe.

Comment: Its not there...Tried searching local workspace also.